# If $ \int_{0}^{2}\frac{ax+b}{(x^2+5x+6)^2}dx = \frac{7}{30}\;,$ Then value of $a^2+b^2$

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

> If the value of Definite Integral $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2}\frac{ax+b}{(x^2+5x+6)^2}dx = \frac{7}{30}\;,$ Then value of $a^2+b^2$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ We can write it as $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2}\frac{a(2x+5)+(2b-5a)}{(x^2+5x+6)^2}dx = \frac{7}{30}$$

So we get $$\int_{0}^{2}\frac{a(x^2+5x+6)^{'}}{(x^2+5x+6)^2}dx+{(2b-5a)}\int_{0}^{2}\frac{1}{(x+2)^2(x+3)^2}dx = \frac{7}{15}$$

So we get $$-a\left[\frac{1}{(x^2+5x+6)}\right]_{0}^{2}+(2b-5a)\int_{0}^{2}......=\frac{7}{15}$$

Now How can I solve second Integral, Help Required, Thanks

Comment: No general method in your bag of tricks, to find the coefficients $(u,v,w,z)$ in $$\frac{ax+b}{(x^2+5x+6)^2}=\frac{u}{x+2}+\frac{v}{(x+2)^2}+\frac{w}{x+3}+\frac{z}{(x+3)^2}\ ?$$ Or, using your reduction, in $$\frac{1}{(x^2+5x+6)^2}=\frac{u}{x+2}+\frac{v}{(x+2)^2}+\frac{w}{x+3}+\frac{z}{(x+3)^2}\ ?$$

Comment: The integral equals $$b \left(\frac{23}{60}-\log\left(\frac{36}{25}\right)\right)+a \left(-\frac{9}{10}+\log\left(\frac{7776}{3125}\right)\right)$$ but a second linear constraint is missing in order to fix $a^2+b^2$.

Comment: Can we put terms containing $\log$ part to zero.

Comment: Maybe the original question was to find the *minimum* or *maximum* value of $a^2+b^2$? As stated, there are infinite possible values for $a^2+b^2$.

Comment: $1=(2x+7)(x+2)^2-(2x+3)(x+3)^2\Rightarrow \frac{1}{(x+2)^2(x+3)^2}=\frac{(2x+7)(x+2)^2-(2x+3)(x+3)^2}{(x+2)^2(x+3)^2}= \frac{2}{x+3}+\frac{1}{(x+3)^2}-\frac{2}{x+2}+\frac{1}{(x+2)^2}$

Comment: To  Jack D'Aurizio , We can Write $\displaystyle \frac{1}{(x+2)^2(x+3)^2} = \left(\frac{1}{x+2}-\frac{1}{x+3}\right)^2\;,$ Now after solving the Integral We get $\displaystyle \left(\frac{46b-62a}{60}\right)+(4b-3a)\ln(\frac{6}{5}) = \frac{7}{15}$

Comment: Better start with $$\dfrac{d\left(\dfrac A{x+3}+\dfrac B{x+2}\right)}{dx}=\dfrac{ax+b}{(x^2+5x+6)^2}$$